# standard-based file format for sharing office details on website

Tags: json, xml, web-services, share

We have several partner institutions, each with several offices (**each office has an address, email, phone, opening times**). These informations are published on their respetive web sites.

We would like to aggregate the informations about all the partners offices in one single platform (i.e. our mobile app).

Of course, scraping of each different web site could be an approach, but we would like to ask the cooperation of our institutional partners.

The basic idea would be to ask to each partner institution to publish information about their offices in an XML (or JSON) file (on their web site), so that it could be periodically processed by our software.

**So, I am looking for suggestions regarding the format for this XML (or JSON) file to be used to share office informations publicy.**

This question is **not** about which is better between JSON and XML.

A first candidate could be an RSS feed, which (in my opinion) is simple and should be supported by most content management system. Although, RSS is about sharing news, not office details...

Any suggestions are welcome: in terms of eventual standards which can be applied to this kind of office information (address, email, phone, opening times).

Thanx!

(the partner institutions are about 30, and each one has their own personalized web site, so a custom scraper for each web site would be required)

update: added reference to JSON format, thanx to Mirko Eberlein

update #2: the question is not "which is best between JSON and XML" but  if there are any standards (like RSS) which can be used for this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

i read you want to get Data from other sites on your site. What kind of application you have? The simple way is create an java script onload function who read out the data form all the files. I woult define for example an json format what is much easyier to read in js.
What kind of cms u use?

Comment: on our side, we use python and django. the use of JSON is interesting, thanx